# Archiving files with tar using the -C option?

Tags: linux, tar

After completing this I'd like the files `tt` and `yy` to be at the root of the archive (The directory `stuff` that contains them should not be included):

```
ole@mk:~$ mkdir stuff
ole@mk:~$ touch stuff/tt
ole@mk:~$ touch stuff/yy
ole@mk:~$ tar -cvzf stuff.tar.gz -C stuff
tar: Cowardly refusing to create an empty archive
Try 'tar --help' or 'tar --usage' for more information.
```

Thoughts?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As you probably understand,
your `tar` command (the fourth command in your question) is equivalent to

```
{ cd stuff; tar -cvzf ../stuff.tar.gz; }
```

But that command fails with the same error message,
because you aren’t telling it what files to archive. 
You need to say

```
tar -cvzf stuff.tar.gz -C stuff .
```

to say “change directory to `stuff`
and then archive (all files in) the current directory.”